# Why this code's result is 37?

Tags: php

Why this code's result is 37?

```
$a = 11 + 011 + 0x11;
var_dump($a);//result = 37
```

Comment: what's the question??? (int)011 -> 9  (int)0x11 -> 17 , so 11 + 9 + 17 = 37

Comment: Was this a homework question?

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = 11    +   011    +   0x11;
     ^          ^          ^
  base 10    base 8       base 16
    11     +   9      +    17          = 37
```

**Base 16**

```
0x11 =   1 * 16^1 (16)
       + 1 * 16^0 ( 1)
     -----------------
      0x11        (17)
```

**Base 8**

```
11 = 1×8^1 + 1×8^0 = 8+1 = 9
```

**Table**

```
base 8  Decimal 
0        0
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6        6
7        7
10       8
11       9            -> Here
12       10
13       11
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The result is 37 as the sum of all the numbers evaluates to 37.

`011` - This is considered an octal value (as it begins in 0), thus is equates to 9.

`0x11` - This is considered a hex value, thus it equates to 17

Hence:

`11 + 011 + 0x11`,

Can be written as:

`11 + 9 + 17 = 37`

Perhaps take a look at the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)